# Resizable div not responding to percentage height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs within a parent, one has .resizable, however i want it to have a max height in percentages, I have found the code that manages to resize the DOM, but i can't get it to work for me, I have got pretty close.

I want the resizable div to have a max height of 70% and min height of 30% (originally starting point)

[Added a picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52CKU.png)

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brad211/87L7sfLr/2/)

I have the follwoing code setup

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="div">
<h4>header</h4>
<h4>header</h4>
<h4>header</h4>
<h4>header</h4>
<h4>header</h4>
<h4>header</h4>
<h4>header</h4>
<h4>header</h4>
<h4>header</h4>
<h4>header</h4>
</div>
<div class="resizable" id="resizable">
```

**CSS**

```
  .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}



.div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #0098ff;
}

.resizable {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#resizable").resizable({
    autoHide: true,
    handles: "n",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        var parent = ui.element.parent();
        ui.element.css({
            height: ui.element.height()/parent.height()*100+"%"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @MuhammadAref 's answer to constrain height -

After some playing around you won't easily get this to work without putting all the blue-colored content into its own container. Basically, jQuery UI relies on relative positioning, and we have to use this for the resizable element (or it can't be resized in some tests, turns out).

I've got [the desired effect working on this forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9f1Ljnw/13/) and this is how:

#### CSS

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.n-resizable-topcontent {
  height: 70%;
  background-color: #0098ff;
}
.resizable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="n-resizable-topcontent">
      <div> some text here </div>
      <div> some text here </div>
      <div> some text here </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resizable">resizable</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### Javascript

```js
$(".resizable").resizable({
    autoHide: true,
    handles: "n",
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
            // parent
        var parent = ui.element.parent();
        var parent_height = parent.height();

        // Get the min value of height or 70% of parent height
        // Get the max value of height or 30% of parent height
        var height = Math.min(ui.size.height, parent_height * 0.7);
        height = Math.max(height, parent_height * 0.3);

        // Set height for resizable element, and do not change top position.
        // Instead the previous element - content container - will be adjusted.
        ui.size.height = height;
        ui.position.top = 0;

        // make the content container's height 100% of parent, less .resizable
        ui.element.prev('.n-resizable-topcontent').height( parent_height - height );
    }
});
```

#### How?

I've divided `#wrapper` into two elements, one you had (resizable) and a new one to hold all the contents - a content-container. I've given it a class `n-resizable-topcontent` so it sticks out.

The main change from your initial code is to change the height of the new container element rather than using the `top` position of the resized element. jQuery UI will, when sizing in `n` direction, adjust `top` *and* `height` - instead of shifting the element upwards, we shrink the element above it (the container) and anything inside it implicitly.

If you're concerned about there being too few elements or too many nested elements - it's usually not an issue, it's better to be certain of how it works. Positioning with CSS is not always easy or straightforward, and one of the more difficult things to do is automatic height - it's hard to tell elements to eat up "the rest" of the vertical space without configuring each element to specific heights.

Best advice I can offer there is: keep it simple. If you need a particular element to do too many things, it will quickly become impossible and there's no shame then in using what seems like redundant HTML,css,js etc to position everything as it should be.

If you have more information about what should go in this container / any additional constraints you may have, I can update my answer to suit.

Comment: Also, looking around there is a more recent set of CSS properties called [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) - It's been a couple of years since I've been bothering to keep up with CSS standards, but depending on your needs with jQuery this _might_ be something that can help you (or it could get in the way as with changing `position` property showed me)

Comment: thanks, this worked out to be more complicated than what i thought, I am avoided flex box as i have experience with it tending to break. 

I wish to put google maps into the "resizable" div (i.e the one that goes from 30%-70% on resize). I have nested id=maps within the resizeable div, but this is not appearing. Is this something specific to maps.. I have forked your [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/brad211/g1vwazwz/1/)

Is this something specific to maps itself, why it wont appear within resize?

Comment: @BradWalls I can have a look but what you're trying is going to be hard - to really appreciate why I'd suggest running maps in a top-level element just to see how its' html/css is structured (note the `position` properties especially). For a start try to remove all unnecessary `position` properties in your own css, then, you may want a horizontal line for a handle so to not compete with maps for mouse events, lastly i'd check z-order and whether css3 (h/w accel) is the issue as maps uses this extensively (i've had problems with safari on win xp eating 2gb of ram because of maps on one design)

Comment: (that problem is ancient and won't happen now, but it's to serve as an example that maps _can_ be buggy with other html/css - i never did have an issue with maps except for that one site i made, even had a photo of safari rendering the screen upside down momentarily as a result)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have since replaced the handle with a thicker horizontal line to not compete with maps, this might be a topic for another question. [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/brad211/h9f1Ljnw/14/)

Comment: no worries - yeah I'd say so, it's something separate to alignment / resizing vertically and more to do with maps + jqueryui compatibility / interoperability. I don't doubt someone has dealt with this before by now and would be able to assist, unfortunately beyond my experience to say for sure how it should work.

Comment: Ill tag you if i end up getting there. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You want the resizable element to be min `30%` and max `70%` of its parent's height

```
$("#resizable").resizable({
    autoHide: true,
    handles: "n",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        var parent = ui.element.parent();
        var height = ui.element.height();

        // Get the min value of height or 70% of parent height
        height = Math.min(height, parent.height() * 0.7);

        // Get the max value of height or 30% of parent height
        height = Math.max(height, parent.height() * 0.3);

        ui.element.css({
            height: height + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```

Update:
You should use `resize` event instead of `stop`, to prevent the user from over resizing

> http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize
>
> resize( event, ui )Type: resize
>
> This event is triggered during the resize, on the drag of the resize
> handler.

Comment: This is good but what about the drag handles? FYI this would give the appearance that you can resize out of the 30%-70% bounds but it will snap back.

Comment: @XerenNarcy You mean, if the user resize it to `90%`, and stop dragging, it will go back to `70%`?

Comment: yeah, but also it's doing some funny things. i've [forked the fiddle instance with your solution](https://jsfiddle.net/vk3s8r9s/1/) and it looks like `position:relative` is the culprit for the other strange behavior. from experience you may want `top:;bottom:;position:absolute;` to scale sections of the screen reliably, but there's other ways too.

Comment: just to clarify the `position:relative` thing is not an issue with your solution per se, but a potentially fundamental incompatibility between `resize` mechanics and `position:relative` - the bottom of the page generates excess space proportional to the resized element's height.

Comment: Thanks @XerenNarcy i Have made the parent:fixed and the children to absolute.

However the code is still behaving odly... even with the event resize applying the same parameters. [forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brad211/k7ejgftp/)

Comment: @BradWalls ill have a look tonight if still unsolved, it's a bit too complex for the headspace im in right now.